# how to loop through an object and test for if it's the only key present

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using jQuery.serializeJSON (https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON). Basically, I have a form like:

```
<input name='store[products][][type]' type='text' value='TableSaw' />
<textarea name='store[products][][description]'></textarea>
<textarea name='store[products][][price]'></textarea>
```

Which when serialized looks like:

```
{"store":{"products":[{"type":"TableSaw","description":"Really cool saw, should buy it ","price": "20.99"}]}}
```

The user can change/delete/ description, price, and other attributes.Basically, what I want to do is test if type is the only key present.

Right now it looks like:

```
{"store":{"products":[{"type":"TableSaw"}]}} //JUST TYPE IS SENT TO DB. NOT WHAT I WANT
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
{"store":{"products":[]}} //WHAT I WANT TO SEND TO DB.
```

if only type is set, and nothing else.

Comment: There is magic way to do this. You need a simple `if` statement. You've given us the pseudo code for it, so just implement that in real code.

Comment: what are u using in backend ?? or u can use if statement incase u r using ajax

Comment: @meagar, I guess I didn't make my question clear enough. It'd be simple if I was just going to do something to just see if `description && price` were null, but I have dynamic keys (for example, like Color and Size, like I mentioned in my question). Is there a way to delete if ONLY type is set, and all other key/values are blank?

Comment: Then, you're just asking how to get the keys for an object, so you can test whether `type` is the only key present. See the duplicate.

Comment: @meager, Thanks for the reference, but does this question really count as a duplicate? I'm not asking "how to get the keys for an object", I'm asking "how to loop through an object and test for if it's the only key present". I edited the title to make this question better.

Comment: @meager, I've edited the question content as well now.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for (var i=0; i<store.products.length;i++) {
     if (!isValid(store.products[i])) {
          delete store.products[i];
     }
}

function isValid(product) {
   return (product.type && product.description && product.price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when you assign the json definition to an object like this

```
var data = {"store":{"products":[{"type":"TableSaw","description":"Really cool saw, should buy it ","price": "20.99"}]}};
```

All you need to do is to test the type of the `description` and the `price` elements if they don't exist you make the array `products` empty like this :

```
if( typeof(data.store.products[0].desctiption) == 'undefined' || typeof(data.store.products[0].price) == 'undefined')
    data.store.products = [];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was really unclear on my question, I've now edited to be more clear. Basically, I am trying to test if type is the ONLY key/value set in the object, and if it is, then delete the entire object.